# PHP & MySQL - How to check if an array is empty or not in a function

Tags: php, mysql

I was wondering how can I check if an array is empty or not in a function

Here is part of my code.

```
if (!mysqli_query($dbc, $sql)) {
        trigger_error(mysqli_error($dbc));
        return;
} else {
    $t = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $t[] = $row[0];
    }
}

if($tr > 0){
    $ts = array_sum($t);
}
```

Comment: `$t[] = $row[0]` is going to give the same value to every element in the `$t` array. You need to put a counter in there.

Comment: `if (empty($array))` and it doesn't matter inside of function or not

Comment: @JMC Creative, exactly where?

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel, "not in a function" but "if an array is empty or not"

Comment: @tang, before the while statment you could put ` $i = 0 ` then inside the while loop, you would put ` $t[] = $row[$i]; $i++ `

Comment: still there is no sense. what's the difference if gonna check it ina function? functions bears the same code as the rest of the script

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel, i did not no that, and no need to be rude. -1 for you being you.

Comment: LOL what a language! Your mom should spank you for this, little rascal :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the empty() function:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

Comment: Not a function, but a language construct. Slightly different.

Answer (score 1):

Loose equivalency checking returns `false` on an empty array

```
if(array()) // returns false
```

http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php

Answer (score 0):

Use [count()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) to count the number of elements in the array.

Answer (score 0):

An easy method would be to use the [count function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.count.php).

For example:

```
if(count($sourceArray) != 0) {
    // Do exciting things here...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
empty($t);
```

gives you `true` if `$t` is considered empty.

Answer (score 0):

To check if array is empty:

```
if (sizeof($arr) == 0)
{
    //Empty array
}
```

To check whether an element exists in an array or not:

```
if (in_array($element, $arr))
{
     //Element found in the array
}
```